# How do you track down why a Vim plugin does not work?

Tags: vim, plugin

I have installed the plugin vim startify which worked fine in my remote server where I use it. Something happened (I think an upgrade) and the plugin no longer seems to work! But I don't get any error e.g. when vim starts. How do you track down the problem in such cases?

Comment: You've submitted (and then withdrew) the same imprecise question already [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032516/vim-plugin-stopped-working-how-is-this-usually-fixed). Just repeating it here won't make it better...

Answer (score 3):

First, check that the plugin is correctly installed; its scripts must appear in `:scriptnames`.

Then, check what artifacts it defines (commands, mappings, autocmds), and verify they're there via `:verbose map ...` and `:verbose command ...`, `:verbose autocmd ...`

Finally, trigger the plugin functionality while capturing a log with `vim -V20vimlog`. In the log (or alternatively with `:debug`ging), you can observe what the plugin is doing, and hopefully locate when and where it goes wrong.

Comment: +1.Very useful info. Concerning `Finally, trigger the plugin functionality while capturing...` how can I do that?The plugin is supposed to start as soon as I start  vim

Comment: For that, it probably defines an `:autocmd VimEnter *`. Is this defined? Does it appear in the log file?

Comment: When I do `:scriptnames:` it does not appear as part of the list.When I do `vim -V20vimlog` I don't see any output.When I do `:debug` in vim I get:`E471: Argument required`

Comment: Actually I found the `vimlog`!I see the plugin mentioned, but I don't know what am I supposed to look for.